# How do I disable my laptop keyboard without also disabling the touchpad?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, touchpad

Disabling or uninstalling the keyboard doesn't work, so I update it to a non-working driver as a workaround. When I do this, the keyboard successfully doesn't work anymore, but then neither does the touchpad. How do I do this without also disabling the touchpad? Is there an alternative touchpad driver I can use? The laptop is HP Stream serial number 5CD83379CQ Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

The wiring for the keyboard and touchpad are often one and the same or they are shared.

Disabling the keyboard from the Device Manager is the maximum you can do,
if it can be done without disabling both devices.

You could explore the idea of physically detaching the keyboard's ribbon cable
from the motherboard or from its shared connection with the touchpad,
but there is a potential for causing a permanent damage.